# Spring boot ignores application.properties file in IntellijIdea

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, application.properties

After I cloned my spring-boot application from repository it fails to start with error:

"Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured."

My application.properties file:

```
server.port=1598
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Server
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

When I removed this file - nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to mark directory "resources" as Resources Root in Idea.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMLiN.png)